# Using jQuery and PHP to Display Data

Tags: php, jquery

**Background**

I don't know much about PHP or jQuery, and I was wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible. I have a server with access to a database behind a firewall. I want to use jQuery to push the data out to an external server's PHP script every 5 seconds where it will be displayed publically. This external server does not have access to a database that I know of. If this is possible, what would I have to put in the PHP script?

**What I Have So Far**

internalServer.js:

```
function timedPost() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://externalserver/display.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"some":"json"}',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    setTimeout("timedPost()", 5000);
}
```

externalServer.php

```
<?php 
    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
        case 'http://internalServer': case 'https://internalServer':
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fix this! `data: {some:"json"}` and `setTimeout(timedPost, 5000);`

Comment: Do you have any actual problem using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)?

Answer (score 0):

I've not done cross-domain stuff, but a quick check on the jQuery site makes it sound like it ought to be possible.

See if what you have already works, first - you haven't said. Presumably externalServer.php would also do the data logging you need? Use Firefox/Firebug or the dev tool in Chrome/Safari to watch the AJAX operation in progress, and to see whether it comes back with HTTP response code 200 (everything was ok).

If this doesn't work, do the AJAX operation to your own server and then, inside the PHP code that handles this, use curl or similar to post the data to a different script on the external server. This is "proxying" the HTTP request, and although it requires another request/response hop, is probably how I would do it.

Edit: aaahhhh, I see why you have your header() statements above. You want your script to do the AJAX logging *and* your display on the external server. That's not possible - have one script for doing the AJAX logging, and another for the display. As I suggest in the comments, log to a local file (or a [sqlite](http://php.net/sqlite) database, which is just a file) and display that data with a different script.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was getting the 200 status code in Firebug so I guess that means the data's being sent and received okay? I literally know next to nothing about PHP. Can you, or anyone else for that matter, guide me to writing the code necessary to display/read/store/whatever the data I'm getting in the POSTs if that makes any sense?

Comment: Yes, the 200 is a good sign. If you check the correct tab in Firebug, you can also see whether the data you are sending is correct. If that is good also, then all you need do in externalServer.php is log the data. Of course you could use a database, but if you don't have one to hand, log it to file and get another script to display it (see my edit).